# Will newCachedThreadPool has no upperlimit for the thread number in the pool?

Tags: java

I checked the document, no parameter to specify the number of threads when using cachedthreadpool, does it mean the thread number will be increased under heavy load until the system resource has been used up?

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not sure it would consume all resources, it is unbounded (well, unless you can spin up `Integer.MAX_VALUE` threads). It will still reuse threads and remove unused ones where possible. However you can simply use the constructor yourself:

```
ExecutorService myPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(0, 30, //30 thread cap
        60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, //thread expiration time
        new LinkedBlockingDeque<>(), //infinite queue, can use other synchronous collections
        r -> new Thread(r, /* thread name */)); //thread factory
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind `newCachedThreadPool` is to create short lived threads so that the same can be reused instead of creating new threads.

Still let's assume that there is a scenario where the number of threads is equivalent to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`; but still the number of CPU cores available will be say 4.

As per the below mentioned code :

```
public static ExecutorService newCachedThreadPool() {
        return new ThreadPoolExecutor(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE,
                                      60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                                      new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>());
}
```

The `newCachedThreadPool()` method internally creates a new `ThreadPoolExecutor` with `maximumPoolSize` as `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and `keepAlive` time as 60second.

The javadocs for `keepAlive` suggests :

> **keepAliveTime** when the number of threads is greater than the core, this is the maximum time that excess idle threads will wait for new tasks before terminating.

Which means that if the number of threads is more than the available CPU cores, the excess thread will be live for only 60secs before being marked terminated.

So there should not be any such scenario where `newCachedThreadPool()` caused the system resources to be fully consumed.